# Flutter Error (E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory) - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, cross-platform, flutter-test, flutter-getx

first of all these errors just appears when i run the app on a real device

the app runs perfectly on android studio emulator

i'm using android studio and Getx package for my flutter project

right after running the app on real device this error appears

```
E/LB      ( 4438): fail to open file: No such file or directory
```

and after opening the drawer in the app => this error appears

```
V/MiuiFrameworkFactory( 4438): get AllImpl object = android.common.MiuiFrameworkFactoryImpl@71c94b4
W/MirrorManager( 4438): this model don't Support
```

and the app doesn't change to the dark mode when i press the change theme button i made

anyone can explain these errors for me , and how can i fix this ??

Comment: Can you provide the complete logcat of error , and keep error one at a time and be more descriptive, so that the community can help you

Comment: Did you solve it? I am facing the same problem